# grep -f patternfile finds either nothing or too much depending on content of patternfile

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, grep

After searching, reading and trying possible solutions for much about `grep` lines with the list of patterns, hence I am writing. It is I know a very basic and have been attended in many forums.

But I am stuck with the following: I have two files, I want to grep those lines from bigger file, which matches with the pattern from smaller file.

I have a file_A.txt (a single column list of patterns to be matched) like:

```
comt241_c0_seq1
comt868_c0_seq1
comt685_c0_seq1
comt7977_c0_seq1
comt6723_c0_seq1
comt363_c0_seq1
comt384_c0_seq1
```

and another file_B.txt (tab delimited, with more entries than file_A)

```
comp5_c0_seq1   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0
comt241_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt868_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt363_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt384_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp429_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp452_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp452_c0_seq2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp483_c0_seq1 33  8   10  32  0   33  8   0   37
comt685_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp494_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt7977_c0_seq1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp564_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp596_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comp653_c0_seq1 10  0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
comp724_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt6723_c0_seq1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I tried `grep -f file_A file_B > file_C`

But it returned an empty file.

So I removed any white spaces from file_A using

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//' file_A > new_file_A
```

but didn't worked out. I have tried a lot things to remove special character or space and to properly delimit file but it either gave me extra entries or nothing.

I think there are some special character either in file_A or file_B, which is bothering.
I am using text wrangler editor.

Is there other way apart from grep of doing this?

Comment: @Roli If the answer by sree solves your issue please take a moment and click the check mark under the vote count to the left of that answer, this will signify to everyone that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site. Do not abuse the possibility to edit the title to indicate a "status change".

Comment: See this post: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the two files with the same contents as mentioned and used `grep` in the same way and it worked fine. I hope you are using the same file names (I see the .txt extension missing in the question).

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ grep -f file_A.txt file_B.txt > file_C.txt
[sreeraj@server ~]$ cat file_C.txt
comt241_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt868_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt363_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt384_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt685_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt7977_c0_seq1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt6723_c0_seq1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[sreeraj@server ~]$
```

You can try `dos2unix` on both the filenames if they are still producting an empty file.

```
dos2unix file_A.txt
dos2unix file_B.txt
```

Comment: I have figured out the problem but not silution: Actually in the list_A.txt there are entries like comt66_c0_seq1, comt66_c0_seq10, comt66_c0_seq11, comt66_c0_seq12. Hence all these type of entries are also in the ouput file. How can I restrict grep for exact pattern. Any idea?

Comment: Solved: grep -w is what I was looking for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Your grep command seems correct. Except you are using different filenames:

```
grep -f list_A list_B
```

instead of

```
~$ grep -f fileA.txt fileB.txt
comt241_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt868_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt363_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt384_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt685_c0_seq1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt7977_c0_seq1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
comt6723_c0_seq1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Sorry I made a typing error while explaining, but in actual case I am using correct file names. I have edited my question.